# How can I use SQLite DB browser to copy a Create table statement form one data base to another?

Tags: database, sqlite

Suppose one wants to copy a table structure, i.e., the Create statement, from first.db into file second.db. How can this be done in SQLite DB browser?

Answer (score 3):

I did some searching but found nothing applicable. After some fiddling around in the browser, here's what I came up with.

1. Open first.db with the browser. Right-click the wanted table in the database Structure tab and select Copy.
2. Open second.db with the browser. Select the Execute SQL tab and do paste (CTRL-V) to paste it into the panel. It will be selected after the paste.
3. Click on the right arrow icon in the tool bar.

Finished!